# Critique my 10y/o logo and my redesign attempt

Tags: logo, critique

I'm a self employed engineer and 10 years ago when I started I quickly put together my logo. Since then I never really had the time to update it. I'm mostly dealing with machine vision and electrical measurements, so an iris and a signal made sense at the time. The font was a random scifi looking font.

The logo is used mostly black on bright background (white, silver) or white on dark background (blue, grey). The icon is used for software icons (16x16, 24x24, ... up to 256x256). Here is my current logo:

[image: my current logo]

Issues that I am aware of and bother me:

1. Poor legibility of the letter D: it's Diff, not Oiff
2. Poor readability when height is small (mostly on sofware UIs, headers, etc.)
3. The EKG heart signal. A measurement signal is almost never like that.

Now I finally have some time (thanks corona) and decided to update it. My goals are to fix the issues and to not deviate too far from the original design because of brand recognition. Here is my attempt at a redesign:

[image: my redesign attempt]

I altered the proportions, changed the signal, changed the iris to better fit in with the letter d, all small caps for better legibility. I thought about a ligature on the double ff, but it was strange. What do you guys think? Have I missed anything obvious?

Comment: I actually like the lowercase d better. `:)`

Comment: I don't like the fact that you just took the [aperture laboratories logo](https://www.google.com/search?q=aperture+laboratories&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRk6K5xdztAhXQzKQKHT2rAUEQ_AUoAXoECBUQAw&biw=1920&bih=900) from Valve. Aside from potential copyright issues, you'll have to realize that anyone who recognizes this logo will have a bad first impression of you. It's an unnecessary risk and I would try to come up with something original.

Answer (score 6):

Opinions:

Your name in the logo has been Diff. Version "diff" is something smaller. Do not change it.

The image and text size ratio is turned to opposite. Let them look as big, like this:

[image]

Continuity fixes do not change the basic look, it can still be automatically recognized to be the same. But they make it look more carefully made which is a good thing.

Not asked: as you see I changed the skew angle of your original text to make it fit into the new iris. The f-letters are pruned to keep them narrow. Now they a little resemble adjustable spanners or pipe wrenches, but I guess it's no problem.

ADD: if reading it as Oiff is a problem then use more round D. Making it skewed can look not so technical as your original blocky text style, but distort it even more if needed. It's your image. An example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It's a good concept, but still suffers from issue #1 (poor readability), especially when used with a low height. I printed it out and tested it on some subjects. Still got result Oiff, instead of Diff. I'm not too worried about Diff vs diff. Better this, then Oiff which is completely different. Thinking about this some more, it seems it's really hard to distinguish the letters D and O with smaller logos. The radious on the D eventually gets so small that it's difficult to know which it is (without context).

Comment: @diff just make the forward arc of existing D more rounded.